# How to open Finder with python on Mac

Tags: python, macos

I tried code like below

```
import subprocess
import os
path = "/Users/mac/Desktop/test1/test2/"
if os.path.exists(path):
    subprocess.call(["open", "-R", path])
```

The code worked, but actually "/Users/mac/Desktop/test1/" was open and the inside of the test2 directory was not displayed.

I don't want to open test1 directory, but open test2 directory.
What should I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem myself.  subprocess.call is a method that calls the unix command. "open -R" option don't open the Finder, but select the Finder.In other words, if I remove the -R option, Finder will open.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the trailing / in the path and checking if you have the permissions to open test2

Comment: Deleting did not change the result